# How to split character and numbers and concat special symbol in middle in java

Tags: java

String structure/format will always be like characters followed by numbers.For example, I have the string "AA12". 
I want to insert special character($) in between the characters and numbers ie., AA$12.

How to write the code in java?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could use a regular expression. `String.replace(String, String)` comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
String test = "AA12";
String replaceAll = test.replaceAll("(\\p{L})(\\p{N})", "$1\\$$2");
System.out.println(replaceAll);
```